# Error in installation of suitecrm on ubuntu

Tags: installation, apache2, suitecrm

I have been trying to install suitecrm on my ubuntu. For this reason, I‌ followed a youtube tuturial when he hit the virtual host address, then the installation page opened for him.‌However, for me the page in the below image opened.
Please help me on how to install suitecrm on ubuntu[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iddj.png)

Comment: Please share more details: (1) Did you configure a Virtual Host? (2) Please share the steps you followed? (3) Also, what URL did you type in the web browser that led to this page being opened?

Comment: Thank you from your response. I did configure a virtual host at port 80. Regarding the url which I typed, it was my local IP address that I typed and then it led to this page. Furthermore, I changed directory to tmp and then I hit the command git clone https…someth…ghub/salesagility/ suitecrm.git then mv suitecrm /var/www/ then cd /var/www/ then chown -R www-data.www-data suitecrm then chmod -R 775 suitecrm then apt-get install composer then cd suitecrm then composer install then vim/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini then some changes were made in the file

Comment: Thanks for the details. (1) Why did you move SuiteCRM to /var/www/ and not to /var/www/html? (2) Are you using SuiteCRM 7.* or SuiteCRM 8.*? (3) Did you reload the hosts file after making changes to the vHost? Or, did you try a reboot after making all the changes? (4) I believe it is related to the vHost configuration that you did, OR, you moved the source code to a non-public directory.

Comment: Actually I followed a tutorial and what he did I tried to do the same. but, right now, after advancement it gives the following text when I load the link on my web browser: "The recommended PHP version to install SuiteCRM is 7.4.0
Although the minimum PHP version required is 7.4.0, is not recommended due to the large number of fixed bugs, including security fixes, released in the more modern versions.
You are using PHP version 7.2.34-43+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, which is EOL: http://php.net/eol.php.
Please consider upgrading your PHP version. Instructions on http://php.net/migration70."

Comment: I believe you should remain in the Compatibility Matrix shared by SuiteCRM: (1) for version 7.* https://docs.suitecrm.com/admin/compatibility-matrix/ and, (2) for SuiteCRM version 8.* here (https://docs.suitecrm.com/8.x/admin/compatibility-matrix/). Otherwise, although the SuiteCRM will install, it will cause issues down the line.

Comment: Okay. Thank you from your kind advice.‌ I‌ have been trying over it since last week, but still haven't been able to install it or properly run it. In addition, I am required to show something in the office to my reporting person. Anyways, will try to complete it.